# Recebendo hora do usuário

Tags: php, javascript

Sou iniciante em php e estou quebrando a cabeça pra descobrir uma solução.
Tenho o seguinte problema:

Tenho uma aplicação web onde meu usuário constrói  o seu estabelecimento fisico online (hotsite).
E nele é cadastrado toda as infos ... Nele também o meu cliente seta os dias e horários de funcionamento. Ao acessar o site do meu cliente, há uma label dizendo se a loja esta ou não aberta. 
Porém, quando há acesso de outras regiões do Brasil. Não tenho controle para mostrar se esta aberta ou fechada devido ao fuso horário.

Gostaria que, quando o terceiro entrasse no site do cliente, retornasse a sua hora local e, assim, efetuar uma conversão de horário.

Não tenho ideia alguma de como fazer essa verificação. Já vasculhei a internet em busca de soluções  sejam em javascript, PHP e afins. Não achei nada.

Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1):

Eu posso até não ter entendido o problema mas se entendi vou tentar responder o melhor que dá.

Provavelmente você não achou uma informação porque não dá para fazer isto de forma confiável. Então ao invés de dizer para você como fazer, o melhor que eu posso lhe responder é: não faça!

Você terá que pegar uma informação que você não tem controle. Além disto não é só o horário que vai determinar se a loja está aberta ou fechada. Se você colocar que está aberta e por alguma razão não estiver você estará enganando a pessoa. Até mesmo se for culpa dela.

Além disto de que vale dizer que está aberto se fechará em 30 segundos ou 30 minutos e ela precisará atravessar a cidade?

Então coloque o horário de funcionamento. Esta informação é muito mais útil para quem está acessando o *site* do que dizer se a loja está aberta. A [experiência do usuário](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_experience) será melhor.

Há toda uma ciência que estuda este tipo de coisa e por mais que possa parecer que está fazendo algo diferente no fundo ninguém quer isto de fato porque esta funcionalidade traz mais prejuízos que lucros.